# Use Precompiled Library in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, precompiled

Is there a way to use a pre-compiled library in Flutter?
There is no source code, for example in C ++, for which a simple bridge would be sufficient. The library is already precompiled and could, for example, be added as a file with the assets.